# Script for deleting multiple directories based on directory name using shell or bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, delete-file

I am trying to write a shell script which removed the directories and its contents based on directory name instead of last modified time.

I have following directories in `/tmp/` location

```
2015-05-25
2015-05-26
2015-05-27
2015-05-28
2015-05-29
2015-05-30
2015-05-31
```

Now I would like to delete all the directories till `2015-05-29`. Last modified date is same for all the directories.

Can any one please suggest?

Comment: `rm -rf /tmp/2015-{{01..04}-*,05-{01..29}}` ? Deletes from 1st Jan 2015 to 29th May 2015.

Comment: @anishsane * doesn't expand in brackets does it ?

Comment: It does: `touch 2015-{{01..04}-1,test}; ls 2015-{{01..04}-*,test}`

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward but not flexible way (in bash) is:

```
rm -rf 2015-05-{25..29}
```

A more flexible way would involve some coding:

```
 ls -d ./2015-* | sort | sed '/2015-06-02/,$d' | xargs rm -r
```

1. Sort lexcially all the directories follow the name pattern 2015-*
2. Use 'sed' to remove all files after (inclusive) 2015-06-02
3. Use 'xargs' to delete the remaining ones

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is:

```
rm -r /tmp/2015-05-2?
```

If you want to keep 2 folders, try:

```
ls -d ./2015-* | sort | head -n -2 | xargs echo
```

Replace `-2` with the negative number of folders to keep. Replace `echo` with `rm -r` when the output looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

The intention of this question is to find directories whose names indicate a timestamp. Therefore I'd propose to calculate those timestamps to decide whether to delete or not:

```
ref=$(date --date 2015-05-29 +%s)
for d in ????-??-??; do [[ $(date --date "$d" +%s) -le $ref ]] && rm -rf "$d"; done
```

`ref` is the reference date, the names of the other directories are compared to this one.